# What is the correct plural of Lord/Lady justice?

Tags: irregular-plurals

Members of the Court of Appeal of England & Wales, and the Court of Appeal for Northern Ireland are styled Lord (or Lady) Justice.

What is the correct plural? In American and Canadian English, one might say Associate Justices of Puisne Justices respectively, but is Lord and Lady Justices correct? Or should it really be Lords Justice or Lords Justices?